# MySQL Workbench - Criar Base de Dados com base no Modelo EER (Opções do Forward Enginner)

Tags: mysql

### Dúvida:

---

No WorkBench criei a tabela no `EER Diagram` e agora quero connectar ao Hostname 127.0.0.1.

O caminho que faço é `Forward Engineer` -> `Next` -> e depois tenho uma serie de opções, tenho de selecionar quais?

---

**Opções:**

- Drop object before Each Create
- Object Generate DROP SCHEMA
- (...)

Comment: Pode colocar a imagem na qual tela parou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É essa tela aqui?

[image: Opções do Forward Engineer do MySQL Workbench]

Vamos lá, uma por uma:

- **DROP Objects Before Each CREATE Object:** exclui as tabelas antes de criá-las novamente
- **Generate DROP SCHEMA:** exclui o banco de dados/schema antes de criá-lo novamente
- **Skip creation of FOREIGN KEYS:** não cria as chaves estrangeiras
- **Skip creation of FK indexes as well:** não cria os índices para as chaves estrangeiras (só se você marcar a opção anterior)
- **Omit schema qualifier in object names:** não prefixar os objetos com o nome do esquema
- **Generate USE statements:** usar afirmações do tipo USE
- **Generate Separate CREATE INDEX statements:** não criar os índices dentro dos comandos de geração de tabelas
- **Add SHOW WARNINGS after every DDL statement:** selecione essa opção para a adicionar os comandos de SHOW WARNINGS no output; com isso exibe-se eventuais avisos quando o output for executado, o que é bom para fins de debugging
- **Don't create view placeholder tables:** ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
- **Do not create users. Only create privileges (GRANTs):** não cria nenhum usuário, apenas garante os seus acessos às tabelas necessárias (presume-se que os usuários já estejam criados)
- **Generate INSERT statements for tables:** marque essa opção se você edicionou linhas às tabelas geradas e deseja que elas sejam inseridas
- **Disable FK checks for INSERTs:** desabilita a checagem de chaves estrangeiras para os INSERTs.

Referências:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering-sql-scripts.html
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/workbench-en/workbench-en.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Vou seguir os menus do *Wizard* que me aparecem na minha máquina (Fedora com Worbench em Inglês):

1. [Connect Options]  Deves definir o *host* onde te vais ligar. No
   teu caso, *localhost* ou 127.0.0.1; Define o nome do utilizador e
   *password* e clica em "Next".
2. [Options] À partida, deves fazer Next, sem qualquer problema.
   Todas as opções que lá estão servem para usares como migração - no
   caso de já existir a base de dados/tabelas e quereres modificar
   porque fizeste modificações no modelo ER. **"Next"**
3. [Select Options] Nesta janela podes escolher se queres
   exportar/criar só as tabelas, Vistas (View Objects), Stored
   Procedurs (Routine Objects), Triggers e Objectos de Utilizadores
   (User Object); **"Next"**
4. [Review SQL Script] - podes rever as alterações que vão ser
   feitas na BD. Podes alterar alguma coisa que pretendas mas não é de
   todo necessário. **"Next"**

E deverás ter a base de dados criada no host/base de dados que definiste.

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço assim: crio o bd no mysql ai depois abro o workbench e crio meu EER diagrama, dou um ctrl+shift+z e vou avançando... Uma coisa que gosto de fazer é copiar o sql que é gerado, pois se der algum erro eu abro o phpmyadmin seleciono meu bd e insiro o sql que copiei e analiso o erro pra corrigir la mesmo( mas isso é um caso a parte)